# NoSuchMethod error using springboot 1.2.2 Release with spring security oauth 2.0.7 Release

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using springboot version :

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent
```

In another project which I am using spring security oauth version 2.0.7 Release :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
```

The second oauth project is being added as a dependency to the parent project.
Both projects build successfully.
But on Application startup get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAllowEagerClassLoading()Z
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a version of Spring Framework that doesn't meet Spring Boot's requirements.

As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements), Spring Boot 1.2.2 requires Spring Framework 4.1.3 or later. `isAllowEagerClassLoading` was added to `DefaultListableBeanFactory` in Spring Framework 4.1.2 so you must be using 4.1.1 or earlier.

Ideally, you should remove any manual configuration of the versions of your Spring Framework dependencies and allow the dependency management inherited from `spring-boot-starter-parent` to take control. Failing that, you should specify a compatible version manually.